# I have hard time declaring a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I keep getting an error while declaring an employee table. Here's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE employees(
    emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(20),
    last_name VARCHAR(20),
    birth_date DATE(),
    salary DECIMAL(6,2),
    sex VARCHAR(1),
    super_id INT,
    branch_id INT
);
```

I keep getting an error message on line "salary DECIMAL(6,2)". Please help me out!

Comment: `birth_date DATE,` instead (without the parentheses). If that doesn't do the trick, then please paste your actual error message.

Comment: Please pay more attention to the error message. You missed the important part, which says *near* "(), salary...", meaning salary isn't the problem, it's the parentheses before it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is on the `()` just before the salary.

It should just be `birth_date DATE, salary DECIMAL(6,2)...`

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=83fe75e5fa44a76b0e983fadb6c779a3)

Comment: Thanks everyone! I removed the parenthesis after DATE and it worked!